# Show that the following function is primitive recursive

Tags: computer-science, computability

Let $f$ be a function defined by
 \begin{array}{l}
 f(0)=1;\quad f(1)=2;\quad  f(2)=3;\quad f(n)=0 \mbox{, for $n>2$}
 \end{array}

How to show that $f$ is primitive recursive?

Comment: Doesn't this just require the axiom that a 0-ary constant function is primitive recursive?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/complearn/chapter2.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjlkJ6tu4fMAhUFPCYKHRLXAUYQFggdMAE&usg=AFQjCNFoSm5pgah_131ozyjoiNDlSltT3Q&sig2=mp4LGgmr_HhCqPVnQSg10g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Proposition.** Let $g(x)$ be a primitive recursive function and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all but finitely many values of $x$. Then $f(x)$ is also a primitive recursive function.

*Proof.* Let $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ be the set $\{x \mid f(x) \neq g(x)\}$. Let $b_i = f(a_i), i = 1,\dots, n$. Then we can define $f(x)$ using $g(x)$ and other primitive recursive functions and substitution:
$$f(x) = g(x)\cdot\mbox{sg}\left(|x-a_1|\cdot\ \dots\ \cdot |x-a_n|\right) + \sum_{i = 1}^n b_i\cdot\overline{\mbox{sg}}|x - a_i|,$$
where $$\mbox{sg}(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } x \neq 0,\\
0, & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}
\qquad \overline{\mbox{sg}}(x) = 1\ \dot{-}\ \mbox{sg}(x),$$
$$|x - y| = (x\ \dot{-}\ y) + (y\ \dot{-}\ x), \qquad x\ \dot{-}\ y = \max(x - y, 0).$$

Now apply this proposition with $g(x) \equiv 0$ and $\{a_1, a_2, a_3\} = \{0, 1, 2\}$